# SELECT records with condition that filters the last chronilogical multiple and specific value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a joined table that looks like that: 
[image]

my goal is to filter all records that was created after the **last** 'active' value inside `LineStatusName` Column. (the yellow marked rows in the attached image).

here is what i have done so far, it is almost work as desired, but the problem is that the date that returns from the nested select steatment is not the date of the highest chronological datetime value of 'active' and if i try to do `ORDER BY Changes.ChangeDateTim` in the end of the nested select i get a syntax error:

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '30-9000241' to data type int*.

I will be grateful if someone can suggest a better solution to achieve that task or to improve my query.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,LineStatuses.LineStatusName,OrderTypes.OrderTypeName,
Changes.ChangeDateTime,Orders.ProjectNumber,Changes.Comments,Changes.ChangeTypeID
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN LineStatusSettings ON LineStatusSettings.LineStatusSettingID = Changes.NewValue
INNER JOIN LineStatuses ON LineStatuses.LineStatusID= LineStatusSettings.LineStatusID
INNER JOIN OrderTypes ON OrderTypes.OrderTypeID = LineStatusSettings.OrderTypeID
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 194 AND Orders.Deleted=0
AND 
Changes.ChangeDateTime > (
SELECT TOP 1 Changes.ChangeDateTime
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN LineStatusSettings ON LineStatusSettings.LineStatusSettingID = Changes.NewValue
INNER JOIN LineStatuses ON LineStatuses.LineStatusID= LineStatusSettings.LineStatusID
INNER JOIN OrderTypes ON OrderTypes.OrderTypeID = LineStatusSettings.OrderTypeID
WHERE LineStatuses.LineStatusName = 'active' 
) AND OrderTypes.OrderTypeName NOT IN ('disconnected line')
ORDER BY Changes.ChangeDateTime
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an Oracle PL/SQL question.

Comment: taged it as `tsql`. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
with jt as (
      <your query here>
     )
select jt.*
from jt
where jt.date > (select max(jt2.date)
                 from jt jt2
                 where jt2.orderid = jt.orderid and jt2.linestatusname = 'Active'
                );
```